# Android app subscription model that doesn't violate the TOS

Tags: android

I need some clarification on the (ambiguous) Android Terms of Service regarding In app purchases with a subscription model.

We are creating a content-based Android app that we would like to sell in the Market using recurring subscriptions.

Here are my questions:

1. If we use the Android Market in-app billing model, would we need to confirm the purchase every month with the user when we bill their account? Or can we simply ask them when they initially subscribe and then charge them on a monthly basis without a confirmation?
2. Ideally, we really would like to use the Paypal Mobile Payment Library to collect the monthly fee (saves money). If we are collecting our recurring subscription payment each month using Paypal, does this violate the TOS for Android and will our app be pulled by them? Also, we do not want the user to confirm each month that they agree to the charge. We have already have an iphone app released that charges the user on a monthly basis -- we do not need to ask them each month to confirm. The user is simply charged via Apple Subscriptions. We are trying to recreate the same model using Android.

I have looked on various forums for an answer to my second question, but there is so much ambiguity and no one in the Android Community seems to have clearly addressed the answers to these questions.

Thank you in advance....

Comment: At least for #2, this is a legal question that you should probably ask a lawyer.

Comment: You need to address this with the Marketplace team. SO is not a place for getting legal advice.

Comment: @TJCrowder, when I went to the Android Developer page , then refer to Stackoverflow as a 'resource'..... http://developer.android.com/resources/community-groups.html

Answer (score 0):

If you put this on the Amazon Market you can use the Amazon in app billing api. I believe this is also allowed to be used outside the Amazon market